# Which non-parametric test for difference between three groups, of which two are paired?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, nonparametric

I want to compare if three groups are different by a non-parametric test. Now..., the problem is that two groups are paired (prior to treatment and one-year after treatment), and the (reference) group is other healthy individuals.

Is there a simple solution? I am using R,

Comment: Do you want a global test for the three groups with the null hypothesis that the three medians are equal? Or do you want pairwise comparisons? All the tree pairs (control-prior, control-after, prior-after)? Will you draw the same conclusion if one or an other pairwise comparison shows a difference?

Comment: The reference group are not "paired" to the first two groups. That is the problem.  In that case I guess Friedman would have been a good test.

Comment: The pairing structure is clear. But please tell more details - otherwise the answers have to consider many ways that may or may not be appropriate in your setting.

Comment: I need a global test for the three groups with the null hypothesis the medians are equal. Kruskal-Wallis may be an option, but this test is not less powerful in comparing the paired "before"-"after". Subsequently, I need post-hoc tests comparing "before"-"after", "control"-"prior" and "control-after". Which post-hoc test I am not sure. I have been thinking of doing  wilcoxon test with adjusted p-values...

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but I really can not find a way...Does anyone know how I can compare these groups? Do I simply have to disregard that two of the groups are paired? (this does not seem correct to me...)

Comment: Don't mean to *bump*, but hey...it's been over 2 months...That must mean some of you think: 1) This is to simple and he's an idiot -or- 2)This is too complex. ANY HELP WOULD BE GREATLY APRICIATED....